# Ubuntu Snappy Core RPi3 model 3 boot failure

Tags: boot, system-installation, raspberrypi

I've downloaded Ubuntu Snappy core onto a u-SD disk card, and the Raspberry Pi 3 model B fails to boot. The monitor shows a large square-shaped multi-colored palette. The RPi3's green LED light blinks 7 times and then it pauses a second and repeats that blink pattern. I noticed that the web page from which I downloaded at this URL:
https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/raspberry-pi-2/

these instruction do not provide a SHA digest on the download nor do they describe a way to verify the integrity of the u-SD disk contents.
tia,
   George

Comment: hey did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue due to too much free space in front of the first partition on the SD card. I extended this partition via GParted to fill the free space in front of it, then everything worked.

I believe this has something to do with the `bs=32` option.

Hash sums can be found one level higher on the download link; see: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/16.04/release/

fresh and almost ready here are some true snappy aka ubuntu.core images for the raspberryPi3:  http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/xenial/daily-preinstalled/20161027/ but be aware of the new install routine as can be watched here https://youtu.be/QT8QJz82iYg?t=5m2s - the ports outside a vm are still `22` and `4200`.

just tried it and works nicely

Comment: Thank you, as per your advice, I re-partitioned and formatted the u-SD card, dd'ed the ....20161027 image you mentioned above and it booted ok. It did briefly show some "failed" messages during the boot up sequence. After a long pause, it finally prompted me for the system's network configuration. I can now ssh into this system from the network, but the log-in prompt on the HDMI console AFAICT does not have a first time default log-in user id and password.... will look around for guidance on this...

Comment: "There is no default ubuntu user on these images, but you can run `sudo passwd <Ubuntu SSO user name>` to set a password in case you need a local console login."  found here: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/raspberry-pi-2/#first-boot

Comment: if your question was answered, pls don't forget to mark it solved